# Querying multiple tables using Ajax post (PHP-MYSQL)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, http-post

I am trying to do the following:

- Get **TMSGUID** from `Campuses` table by using **ID** (primary key).
- Get **TMSGUID** from `Sites` table.
- Get **ID** and **Description** from `SiteOrganisation` table by using Site GUID.

The php page is getting invoked by a jquery post.

What am I doing wrong as no data is getting returned?

This is the code:

```
<?php

    set_include_path('**********************************');

    //Search Screen
    require_once('vars.php');
    require_once('funcs.php');

    //read the parameter passed through URL
    $organizationID = $_GET['orgID'];

        $servername = "**********";
        $username = "**********";
        $password = "*************";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $OrganisationGUIDSQL = "SELECT TMSGUID FROM Campuses WHERE ID='" . $organizationID . "';";
        $Organisation= $conn->query($OrganisationGUIDSQL);
        $OrganisationGUID = null;


        if ($Organisation->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row = $Organisation->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $OrganisationGUID = $row["TMSGUID"];
            }
        }

        $SiteOrganisationSQL = "SELECT SiteGUID FROM SiteOrganisation WHERE OrganisationGUID ='" . $OrganisationGUID . "';";
        $SiteOrg = $conn->query($SiteOrganisationSQL);
        $SiteGUID = null;

        $OrganisationSitesArray = array();

        if ($SiteOrg->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row = $SiteOrg->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $OrganisationSitesArray[] = $row["SiteGUID"];
            }
        }

        $SiteDescription = null;

        $Sites = array();


        foreach($OrganisationSitesArray as $item)
        {
           $SiteSQL = "SELECT ID,Description, TMSGUID FROM Sites WHERE SiteGUID ='" . $item . "';"; 
           $Site = $conn->query($SiteOrganisationSQL);

        if ($Site->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row = $Site->fetch_assoc())
            {
               $SiteID= $row["ID"];
               $SiteDescription = $row['Description'];
               $SiteGUID = $row["TMSGUID"];

               $Sites[$SiteDescription] = $SiteID;
            }
        }


        }
        $conn->close();

        echo json_encode($Sites);




?>
```

Method that calls the PHP page:

```
function refreshSites() {

    var sitesList = $('#SiteId');

    var OrgID = $("#SitesList").val();
    var SiteID = sitesList.val();

    //remove all current options
    sitesList.empty();
    $('<option />', {value: -1, text: "Any"}).appendTo(sitesList);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "modules/Sites/getSiteList.php",
        data: {orgID: OrgID},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {

            $.each(result, function(name, id) {
                $('<option />', {value: id, text: name}).appendTo(sitesList);
            });

            if (SiteID == 0 || SiteID == null) {
                cleanDropdown("SiteId");
            } else {
                sitesList.val(SiteID);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Failed to load Sites");
        }
    });
}
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

[image: error js]

[image: error response]

Comment: Are you actually giving your true credentials out on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Removed the credentials.

Comment: @Brian It is still available if you check the history. You may want to delete the post and recreate.

Comment: @mulquin It's not that much of an issue since it's used only for testing purposes.

Comment: @mulquin Even though the post get deleted, the question is still available for all >10k-rep user. The OP might **want to change his database password on the server ASAP**

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($array as $item)
```

Where is the $array variable getting set ?

Also, what are you hoping to accomplish here?   $OrganisationSitesArray[] will not display anything.

```
 $SiteSQL = "SELECT ID,Description, TMSGUID FROM Sites WHERE SiteGUID ='" . $OrganisationSitesArray[] . "';";
```

Shouldn't the variable for query be SiteSQL?

```
foreach($OrganisationSitesArray as $item)
        {
           $SiteSQL = "SELECT ID,Description, TMSGUID FROM Sites WHERE SiteGUID ='" . $item . "';"; 
           $Site = $conn->query($SiteOrganisationSQL);
```

Comment: Hi, that was a typing error. updated the question with the fixed source.. Changed to $OrganisationSitesArray and $item respectively. I still get the popup message 'Failed to load Sites'

Comment: Yes, you are right. Changed it and still got an error (from js). Changed to $SiteSQL.

Comment: what JS error are you getting?   Is your console showing any data ?  (click network then click on the ajax file in the list)

Comment: Can you go to this chat room ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80778/question-querying-multiple-tables-using-ajax-post-php-mysql